# Why does a simple UPDATE statement sometimes take a few seconds to run?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Our web app automatically emails us when a page execution goes beyond a second or two with timings for running each SQL statement. We track what pages each user is browsing on each page load and this query sometimes takes a couple of seconds to run (we get a number of these automatic emails telling us a page has taken longer than a couple of seconds at the same time).

```
UPDATE whosonline
SET datetime = GETDATE(),
    url = '/user/thepage'
WHERE username = 'companyname\theusername (0123456789)'
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Normally it runs in a split second but say every week or so it takes about 2 or 3 seconds for probably a timespan of 10 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like the page execution is what's taking a few seconds, and not necessarily the `UPDATE` statement...correct?

Comment: Perhaps you have enabled autogrowth and your delays happens when it is time to grow your database file(s).

Comment: Could also be blocked by another process.

Comment: @Yuck it's the database statement - the time it takes for the db connection, running the statement, getting the results and closing the connection. Out of say 10 emails that arrive at the same time (all from different online users), it's always delayed for this specific SQL statement.

Comment: In that case I'm with @MikaelEriksson - it's very likely that your database is going through file growth. You should size your database upfront to prevent this from happening in a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to SQL Profiler, you might want to run that on the statement to see if anything is happening on the server that might be causing issues. I'd also check the execution path in Management Studio/Query Analyzer if you can as well. Otherwise, if those don't turn up anything it probably is something to do with the web-side of things, not SQL.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question and there could be a number of reasons:

1. Is there a pattern to what day/time in the week this happens? Maybe your db machine has just come up
2. How many users do you have? Are there indexes to the database?
3. What about the database cache? Is it configured?
4. How do you know it's a database delay and not a network delay? Have you tried accessing from the local database server and seen if the delays happen there too?

Comment: IMHO, these should probably have been comments until you have enough information to provide a concrete answer.

Comment: @Yuck as far as I can tell these are very GOOD answers.